# Proof that $(a+b, a)$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: vector-spaces

I am aware that the vector $(a+b, a)$ such that $a$, $b$ are real numbers belongs to $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is defined by any vectors $(x_1, x_2)$ such that $x_1, x_2$ are real numbers.

Is there a way to prove that $(a+b, b)$ indeed does equal $(x_1, x_2)$? The reason I am having trouble doing so it because the terms $a+b$ and $b$ have common variables (and hence are related), while $x_1$ and $x_2$ do not.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ then $a+b\in \mathbb{R} $ by closure of real numbers under addition. So, $(a+b, a)\in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Is there a way to clearly demonstrate that the value of a+b does not depend on the value of b? For example, (a, a), if a is a real number, does not belong to R2 since the first element of the vector is also the second (so for example, the vector (2,3) is not possible for (a,a)).

Comment: By definition $E\subset \mathbb{R}^2=\{(a,b):a,b\in \mathbb{R}\}$. If $a\in\mathbb{R}$ then $(a,a)\in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

$\Bbb{R}^2 = \Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{R} = \{(x,y):x,y \in \Bbb{R} \}$ The real numbers are closed under addition, so the addition of any two real numbers is itself a real number. Hence, for any $a,b \in \Bbb{R}$ we know $a+b \in \Bbb{R}$. By definition of $\Bbb{R}^2$ (ALL ordered pairs of real numbers) we know that $(a+b,b) \in \Bbb{R}^2$ because $(a+b,b)$ is an ordered pair of real numbers. If you simply want to pattern match $(a+b,b)$ to some vector $(x_{1},x_{2})$ then let $b = x_{2}$ and $a+b=x_{1}$